# Django - Include dynamic templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to include dynamic template with `include` tag. So basically, when I include template with static path, like below, everything is Ok.

```
{% include "stories/Princess_Run_Story/Princess_Run_Story.html" %}
```

And in my case, I transfer this path in value. And using then, exactly the same.

```
{% include story_counter %}
```

But I catch error below, and main point here, that both value are same, even I manually transfer that path from first example.

```
Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Work-Projects\Web\WebWorkBook\templates\'stories\Cave_Monsters_Story\Cave_Monsters_Story.html' (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\'stories\Cave_Monsters_Story\Cave_Monsters_Story.html' (Source does not exist)
```

UPDATE:

Part of settings: with templates root:

```
....
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

....
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webworkbook.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [MEDIA_ROOT],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
....
```

Another part of path generated from other script. Using `os.path.join` But I can put even sample string path to the value, and transfer to the view. And I will get the same issue.

```
def view_story(request, story_number):
    try:
        story_counter = 'stories/Princess_Run_Story/Princess_Run_Story.html'
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Story does not exist. Something wrong here.")
    return render(request, 'workbook/stories_page.html', {'story_counter': story_counter})
```

Comment: why is there an apostrophe before stories?

Comment: I can tell you what's wrong. The path has a quote in it. Are you certain you don't declare a string variable with a single quotes embedded in it?

Comment: @RobertMoskal Sure, no. I just build path using os.path.join and existing folders.

Comment: @thebjorn It's basic python representation of string. Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: You need to show your TEMPLATES settings; as the previous commenters have said, you somehow have extra quotes embedded in the string.

Comment: It isn't usual to have a path with a quote char in the middle, so yes, that would be my assumption about what was wrong.  I also see that you've installed Python under `Program Files` and not the recommended `c:\python27`.  Lots of programs/modules still have issues with paths containing spaces...

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated some other info.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I found issue, when transferring that path. I also include 'repr' on path value. After remove it, everything is Ok. Please, add answer I will mark as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Fine, but do note you have some very odd code here. Why are you setting MEDIA_ROOT as the base template directory? Why are you catching Question.DoesNotExist from just defining a string, which can never possibly raise that exception?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, Thanks. Probably I'm using just bad names for some settings.